# Harp server produces a lot of whitespace (in HTML)

Tags: html, ejs, removing-whitespace, harp

I am running a blog on Harp. Everything works like a charm but one thing I can’t achieve (and don’t understand). The whole project uses EJS. The problem is in the produced source (HTML) there is a lot of additional whitespace. I’ve tried to reduce it like in case of menus but that did not work.

I would expect reducing of line breaks at least. Typically I use something like this:

```
<li id="nav1" class="main-menu-li-current"><a class="menu-link-current" href="/">home</a></li><!--
    --><li id="nav2" class=""><a class="menu-link" href="/ebooks">ebooks</a></li><!--
    --><li id="nav3" class=""><a class="menu-link" href="/coding">coding</a></li><!--
```

But the problem is in parts dynamically served by EJS, there this does not work, the code looks ugly:

```
      <div class="categories"><!--




           --><span class="category"><a class="category-link" href="/ebooks">ebooks</a></span>
```

Is there any way how to deal with that? If I use minified LESS, I would like to use minified (or at least reasonably looking) HTML as well!

Example code:

```
      <div class="categories"><!--
      <% var categories = public.articles._data[slug].categories %>
      <% if (categories !== undefined) { %>
         <% for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) { %>
           <% if (categories[i] !== "vim tips") { %>
             --><span class="category"><a class="category-link" href="/<%= categories[i]  %>"><%= categories[i] %></a></span>
            <% } else { %>
             --><span class="category"><a class="category-link" href="/vim">vim tips</a></span>
            <% } %>
          <% } %>
        <% } %>
      </div>
```

Comment: Hey, what version of Harp are you using? If you view source on harpjs.com, you’ll see Harp normally minifies all HTML outside of `script`, `style`, and `pre` tags by default.

Comment: Hey, thanks for asking, my version is 0.17.0. I could also stress it is the same, in dynamically viewed sites as well as those compiled.

Comment: I have just realized it improves a lot! when I remove every whitespace (ends of lines as well). Could it be the problem? I use Vim on headless Ubuntu server. I guess everything is UTF-8 there and line ends are of Unix.

Comment: One silly idea :) I could remove the whitespace with yield.replace(...) but this is really ugly method.

Comment: Still not solved :( My actual version of Harp is 0.20.1.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth searching for an existing issue about this on the [EJS repository](https://github.com/tj/ejs), if you feel like this is an issue. The solution would likely come from that rather than Harp. That said, one way to fix this might be to use JS comments in EJS rather than HTML comments, so the comments aren’t compiled at all:

```
<% /* %>
  <h1>Commented out portion of my template</h1>
<% */ %>
```

I don’t think the comments you have in place are necessary at all however. The dynamic EJS are not going to output any HTML where you have commented them out, so maybe the best option is to remove them entirely:

```
<div class="categories">
  <% var categories = public.articles._data[slug].categories %>
  <% if (categories !== undefined) { %>
     <% for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) { %>
       <span class="category"><a class="category-link" href="/<%= categories[i] === "vim tips" ? "vim" : categories[i] %>"><%= categories[i] %></a></span>
      <% } %>
    <% } %>
  <% } %>
</div>
```

Hope that’s helpful!

Comment: Thanks, I would think using of `-%>` could help but no, it does not. No reaction. Unfortunately, using of comments does not help either.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the problem is EJS puts new lines where there are—if they are not commented properly. When I reduce the code into:

```
<div class="categories"><%
   var categories = public.articles._data[slug].categories
     if (categories !== undefined) {
        for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) { %>
       <span class="category"><a class="category-link" href="/<%= categories[i] === "vim tips" ? "vim" : categories[i] %>"><%= categories[i] %></a></span>
      <% }
       }
     }
%></div>
```

… it works.

From my point of view it is much less structured but it works.